# HHL for the pseudoinverse in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, linear-algebra, hhl-algorithm

The HHL algorithm can be modified to compute the pseudoinverse of $A$ as is shown [here](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.150502) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.3171.pdf). Is there anyway to do this in Qiskit without coding the entire thing manually?

Comment: The article is behind a paywall.

Comment: The original HHL publication has it in the discussion section 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.3171.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine if You can decompose the matrix there is a way to build the complete thing more efficiently. However, in the end, You have to be able to construct the matrix one way or another.